# Changing the architecture of fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have been trying to make some changes in fabric architecture, for example, like the processing of parallel transactions from orderer's end, etc.. Now, how would I make the fabric to use my new configurations? Where do I need to make changes? Also, these configurations do not require any changes in the interface, so I think it would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making the changes build the fabric project. You should see new docker images for the latest tag.

You can update docker-compose.yaml to use the appropriate image.